# Gaussian Process doubt for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

How to find hyperparameters (in Gaussian Process) by log marginal likelihood.
Suppose we have mean function as $m=ax^2 +bx + c$.
so we have $hyperparameters = \{a,b,c,sigma_y,sigma_n,l\}$;
How we calculate all these parameters by log marginal likelihood and by partial derivatives?

Comment: What research have you done?  Where have you looked?

Comment: I have researched previous journals for real estate and find these problem. I have found one scholar article by:
Gaussian Process in Machine Learning by Carl Edward Rasmussen
In this paper it is mentioned above problem. I am not able to find out how to calculate those hyperparamters practically (in Matlab).